# SQL Server 2000 to 2008 Migration - ORDER BY Issue when using DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We're currently testing our app from SQL Server 2000 to 2008R2.

The following statement works in 2000, and not in 2008.

```
select distinct left(tz.Zipcode,5) as zipCode
from TerritoryZip tz 
order by tz.Zipcode
```

The error message is:

```
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

The fix is simple:

```
select distinct left(tz.Zipcode,5) as zipCode
from TerritoryZip tz 
order by left(tz.Zipcode,5)
```

However there is a risk that we may not find all the instances of this type of SQL.

So one solution might be to set the compatibility level to 2000 - what are the cons of doing that (e.g. performance of not updating the SQL to use this more strict approach)?

And are there other options/settings, e.g. is there a 'strictness' setting that is enforcing better practices, etc...?

Thanks!!

Comment: OK, I'll bite - why can't you just `order by tz.Zipcode` in SQL 2K8? What data type is `Zipcode`?

Comment: @Yuck: "Msg 145: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the semantics slightly by doing this:

```
SELECT ZipCode FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ZipCode = LEFT(tz.Zipcode, 5)
    FROM dbo.TerritoryZip
) AS x
ORDER BY ZipCode;
```

Doesn't solve the problem really since the query is more verbose and you still can't avoid touching it. The fix you've already suggested is better in my mind because it is more explicit about what is going on.

Not to be harsh, but if you don't think you'll be able to "find all the instances of this type of SQL" then how are you trusting your testing at all?

I would suggest that keeping 2000 mode is not the optimal answer. The reason is this can cause other syntax to break (e.g. the way you might call dynamic management functions - see [this Paul Randal blog post](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-DBA-myth-a-day-%281330%29-you-cannot-run-DMVs-when-in-the-80-compat-mode-%28T-SQL-Tuesday-005%29.aspx) and my comment to it), you also run the risk of perpetuating code that should be fixed (e.g. old-style `*=` / `=*` joins that are valid in 2000 compat mode, but won't be valid when you go from 2008 R2 -> Denali, which doesn't support 2000 compat).

There is no "strictness" setting but you can vote for [Erland Sommarskog's SET STRICT_CHECKS ON; suggestion](http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html).

Comment: no problem.  forgot who I was dealing with, should have said "add a `zipcode = `"

Comment: @JNK what can I say, I'd rather scan the left for a column name than scan each line to find it at the end.

Comment: Your first example would need to order by `tz` or `MIN(zipcode)`. There could be multiple different ZipCodes mapping to the same `tz`

Comment: @Martin weird, I had tried that version against sys.objects and it seemed to work, trying again now I'm not sure what I ran but it certainly wasn't that. [shrug]

Comment: I have used the `GROUP BY` to get around this `DISTINCT` behaviour in the past as well. Can't remember the context. I assume the expression has to be one where it can recognize that there will be a guaranteed one to one mapping.

Comment: @Martin I think it makes the code more self-documenting if you state the intended order either by (a) repeating the expression or (b) using a derived table, or view, or something that abstracts the expression away. While most people want to avoid typing the expression again, as a reviewer far more often than an author, I'd rather see the intention spelled out. `ORDER BY MIN()` or some other workaround would certainly confuse things for me.

Comment: No what I mean is there are some contexts where you **can** do the equivalent of `ORDER BY Zipcode` in a `GROUP BY` but it is disallowed in a `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: @Martin understood, but I'd still prefer to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - it's unfortunately manual functional testing of a large legacy app. For the most part, this has only come up in less than a handful of spots, so compat level would be a huge compromise. I mainly wanted to verify that it's not like a strictness enforcement thing, or perhaps a setting "[x] require identical order by match when using distinct".

Answer (score 3):

> So one solution might be to set the compatibility level to 2000 - what
>   are the cons of doing that (e.g. performance of not updating the SQL
>   to use this more strict approach)?

I suggest you look at the documentation on [ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) which lists dozens of differences between the compatibility levels along with the Possibility of impacts of low medium and high.

Also you should probably run the [Upgrade Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256.aspx) which looks through your components for potential problems that you would need to fix

Comment: +1 for upgrade advisor. This should spot a lot of potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a really good article showing the differences between different compatibility levels in SQL Server 2008 (including performance notes and best practices):  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx.  Even in the example you gave, the SQL in the 2008 version is more intuitive and is enforcing a better best practice.